# Hive Error on windows - return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: windows, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, bigdata

When i'm runnning below query on hive installed on windows - "CREATE TABLE emp.filter AS SELECT id,name FROM emp.employee WHERE gender = 'F';
", Im getting following error --
"FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
2022-08-10 16:17:41,710 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:"

Further on checking yarn logs -
[image: logs]

So when its launching container, there where the problem is i guess -
""Launching container"
[2022-08-10 16:16:48.142]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
'"C:\Users\aksha\Java\jdk1.8.0_202"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

How can i set it right?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
After changing "set JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\aksha\Java\jdk1.8.0_202" to
"set JAVA_HOME=C:/Users/aksha/Java/jdk1.8.0_202" in your hadoop-env.cmd file, should launch container/map-red task.